# Problema def con Flask a través de Python

Tags: python, flask

¡Hola! Estuve probando código con **Flask** a través de Python y me topé con un problema al usar **def**. Al utilizar un return con una **f** fuera de las comillas, me da un error de syntax.

Cuando quito la **f** del código, funciona bien pero la variable que quiero que me de, no funciona. Este es el código el cual intenté y el error de **Python** (utilizo la versión **2.7.17**).

Según he visto, la f suele funcionar como se muestra en la siguiente imagen pero en mi caso me devuelve el error. Estuve dudando si **puede ser la versión** de Python la cual esté interfiriendo pero no encuentro nada parecido según estuve investigando.

[image: Imagen donde la "f" funciona para definir la variable de la URL.]

¿Cuál puede ser el problema? ¡Saludos!

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/<name>")
def user(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0')
```

Devuelve error:

```
root@Moscow ~ # python py.py
  File "py.py", line 7
    return f"Hello {name}!"
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: las `f-strings`  están disponibles en versiones superiores a `python 3.6`

Comment: ¡Gracias! Al parecer existe un package específico para Flask para python3. Lo pude solucionar, gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si lo pudiste solucionar, no seria mejor poner una respuesta? asi otros saben tambien como resolverlo....

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta lo que ha comentado Lucas Damian acerca de que las ***f-strings*** están disponibles a partir de Python 3.6, en el caso de usar Python 2, podrías sustituir la línea del `return` por la siguiente:

```py
return "Hello {}!".format(name)
```